# pygame.error: video system not initialize, using Repl.it

Tags: python, pygame

I get this error when I try to run my pygame code pygame.error: video system not initialized. I'm using Repl.it and am attempting to create an aiming game which can track accuracy and in which you only have 3 lives.

```
import pygame

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False # Here we exit the Loop and execute what after
pygame.quit()

# Play Surface
width = 1080
height = 720
playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Aim Practice')

# Colors
red = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
blue = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
```

[Image of most of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNqSm.png)

https://repl.it/join/dppwnpin-isa__paz (You can view the full code here!)

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: As this [tutorial](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html) on the pygame.org website indicates, you need to call `pygame.init()` after importing it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you event loop is running before anything is initialised.  As @zenofpython says in his answer, the calls to prepare the window must come before the main event loop.

Your main event loop is first, and nothing is setup to run.

Just moving the code around will fix it:

```
import pygame

# FIRST, HANDLE ALL THE INITIALISATION OF PYGAME, FONTS, MIXER etc.
# Play Surface
width = 1080
height = 720
playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Aim Practice')

# Colors
red  = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
blue = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)

# ... AND THE REST

# MAIN LOOP
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False # Here we exit the Loop and execute what after

    playSurface.fill( blue )   # fill the screen
    pygame.display.flip()      # flush all the drawing operations to the window

    fpsController.tick_busy_loop(60)  # clamp the max-FPS

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! <3, although will that somewhat fixed my problem, i am now getting a " exit status 1" error. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: @IsamariPazDiaz - Better ask a new question for that, it shouldn't happen if the code calls `pygame.quit()`, just before the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pygame.display.set_mode` before running your event loop. `pygame.event.get` won't work if you haven't created a window.